# Git listing non-existent remotes

Tags: git, git-branch, git-remote, git-config

I recently made some changes to my remote repos in my Git repo config file.  I renamed the remote names, changing my origin to another remote repo and renaming my old origin.

For example, I had this previously:

```
[remote "origin"]
   url =  blah blah

[remote "future"]
   url = blah blah
```

I went in and changed them so they look like this:

```
# formerly the origin
[remote "old-origin"]

# formerly the future repo
[remote "origin']
```

But now, when I type `git branch -a`, I am seeing branches listed from the old 'future' remote:

```
remotes/origin/HEAD
remotes/origin/branch1
remotes/origin/branch2
remotes/future/branch1
remotes/future/branch2
remotes/old-origin/master
remotes/old-origin/branch3
```

I ran a prune as well as a fetch, etc. but that list just won't be updated.  I did a search on my config file for 'future' and nothing turns up.  Are there any commands I can run to refresh this list and stop looking at that nonexistent remote?

Comment: `git remote --prune future` should have been able to clean your old branches. Try it with the `--dry-run` first.

Comment: If I try 'git remote prune future --dry-run' I get 'fatal: future does not appear to be a git repository

Comment: `git remote prune --dry-run future`: please set the options *before* the parameters :)

Comment: What does `git remote -v` returns? What `future` is referring to?

Comment: That's another strange thing.  git remove -v shows me:

`origin  ssh://correct/path/to/origin (fetch)
origin  ssh://correct/path/to/origin (push)
old-origin ssh://correct/path/to/old-origin (fetch)
old-origin ssh://correct/path/to/old-origin (push)`

So, the 'future' origin isn't even listed

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You used to have a remote named `future`, and you don't now.

Hence, `git remote whatever future` can't help, because there is no remote named `future`.  (Normally `git remote update -p` or `git remote prune`, as in the comments above, would let you get rid of these.)

The simplest option would seem to be to delete them manually:

```
git update-ref -d refs/remotes/future/branch1
git update-ref -d refs/remotes/future/branch2
```

(or `rm -r .git/refs/remotes/future` and/or edit `.git/packed-refs`, depending on whether these refs have gotten packed).

[Incidentally, I'd also run `git config -e` (or `vi .git/config` which is what I usually really do :-) ) and make sure there are no other left-over references to the `future` remote.]

Comment: Fantastic!!  This did the trick.  The refs were packed, so I had to manually remove them from the packed-refs file. 

In addition, the git update-ref also worked on a branch by branch basis, but I actually had quite a bit of branches to remove, so manually editing the packed-refs file worked like a charm.  Thanks again.

Comment: `git update-ref -d refs/remotes/labee/master` didn't help me, only removing the files under `.git/refs/remotes/labee`, `.git/labee` and removing the entry in `.git/packed-refs` did help.