# git branch --all shows obsolete remotes

Tags: git, list, branch

I changed the name of one remote in my git config from `labee` to `EE` and now `git branch --all` shows the following:

```
* master
  remotes/EE/master
  remotes/labee/master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/grunt-3.0-stable
  remotes/origin/master
```

I've invoked the following commands:

```
git prune
git fetch -p
```

but neither of them helped. What can I do? My `.git/config` is as follows:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = false
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    pushurl = https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch.git
    gtPruneOnFetch = true
    gtAlwaysFetchAllTags = true
[remote "EE"]
    url = git@github.com:EE/grunt-contrib-watch.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/EE/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Note that this is *NOT* one of those questions asking for obsolete branches, it's about a non-existing remote.

My git version is `1.8.3.4 (Apple Git-47)`, the default one on OS X 10.9 Mavericks.

Comment: Likely duplicate of [Git listing non-existent remotes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19298154/1256452)